# Area of a one-dimensional set.

Tags: calculus, statistics

Let C be a one-dimensional set and let $\;Q(C)=\int_C e^{-x}\;dx\;$. If $\;C_1=\{x\;:0 \le \;x \le 1\}\;$ and $\;C_2=\{x\;:1 \lt \;x \le 3\}\;$  Find the $\;Q(C_1\cup C_2)\;$.

My solution: $\;Q(C_1\cup C_2)\;$ = $\int_0^1 e^{-x}\;dx\;$ + $\int_1^3 e^{-x}\;dx\;$
$\;= e^{-3}-1\;$

Comment: It should be $1-e^{-3}$

Comment: Note that $\int_0^1 e^{-x}dx=(-e^{-x})_0^1=(-e^{-1})-(-e^{0})$

Comment: yes I remember Now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$Q(C_1\cup C_2)=Q(C_1)+Q( C_2)$$